# Como limitar o envio de dados de um formulário?

Tags: php, javascript, html, arquivo, formulário

Quero impedir que um usuário envie dados mais de 5 vezes por dia; não tenho como usar banco de dados teria que ser gravado em um arquivo `txt`.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Na verdade não, porque desisti da ideia... mas seria legal se tivesse um exemplo pratico usando Cookies para controlar o numero de vezes que podia entrar na página só que não ia ser muito útil por ser fácil de burlar e com a dica já passada aqui parece ser um pouco complicado; por isso a desistência!

Comment: Não tem uma forma confiável de fazer isto, não tem como saber se o usuário é o mesmo. Pode tentar controlar do jeito que quiser e nada vai funcionar confiavelmente, inclusive e especialmente com *cookies*.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível fazer isto, não é o mais adequado mas funciona. A forma mais simples de fazer isto é usar a função [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
file_put_contents($arquivo, $contador);
```

Depois você vai ler o arquivo com [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), incrementar o contador e verificar se já ultrapassou de 5 vezes:

```
$contador = intval(file_get_contents($arquivo));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/LimitSize.php).

Dê uma lida na documentação, tem algumas opções extras nestas funções que podem ser úteis.

Também é possível usar outras funções para manipular o arquivo mais manualmente mas acho que neste caso não faz sentido. Se quiser ver alguma coisa comece por [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php). Na lateral tem todas as funções para manipular arquivos.

O arquivo precisa ter as devidas permissões para conseguir escrever nele. O que pode criar um problema de segurança dependendo de onde este arquivo estiver.

Normalmente cria-se uma pasta separada que fique fora da raiz da hospedagem. Assim seu *script* enxerga o arquivo mas ele não é acessível diretamente pela *web*.

Se você não tiver acesso à uma pasta fora da área do *site* normal (eu trocaria de hospedagem) e não tem controle sobre isto ainda é possível bloquear o acesso externo usando `.htaccess`.